# When the Jacobian is time-dependent, how to analyse stability?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, jacobian, stability-theory

Suppose the jacobian matrix of an equilibrium point is time-dependent, as in the second case of Carlos' answer on this question: [Jacobian matrix of time dependant system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623016/jacobian-matrix-of-time-dependant-system).

Did you know about some reference to deal with stationary points on this case? How to measure stability? I mean, I have a stationary point $X$ and the Jacobian is $t$-dependent. When this does not occur, I calculate the Jacobian on $X$. But now it's not sufficient. Which $t$ should I choose to analyse stability?

Thank you in advance for any comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For definition of stability for non-autonomous systems, see page 44 to page 45 of [Mathematical Definition of Stability of Non-autonomous Systems](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1302/1302.6259.pdf).

For criterion for such stability relating to Jacobian, see [Hartman–Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem), [A generalization of Hartman's linearization theorem](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(73)90245-X), and [On the linearization theorem for nonautonomous differential equations](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bulsci.2014.12.005).

Comment: Thank you so much, your indications helped a lot. Best regards.